# Google Cloud Translation API outputs HTML with syntax errors

Tags: html, node.js, google-translation-api

We're using Google's Cloud Translation API on Node to translate database stored HTML blog posts to around 20 different languages. The translated HTML has a variety of seemingly random HTML syntax errors.

Any idea why this is so and what (if anything) can be done to solve this issue?

As a reference, below are the links to a blog post in English (master source) and the same post translated to Dutch:

[HTML master in English](https://www.qrcode-tiger.com/custom-homepage-with-links-using-qr-codes)

[HTML translated to Dutch](https://www.qrcode-tiger.com/nl/custom-homepage-with-links-using-qr-codes)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Pedro Cristovão, Can you please provide the error messages you are getting?

Comment: The API doesn't produce any error messages. It's the output HTML that has syntax errors.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? Can you provide the HTML output which is having syntax errors?

Comment: Open the pages I submitted in my initial question and you'll see.

Comment: Does this [doc](https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/how-can-i-solve-502-error-bad-gateway-from-cloudflare/) help you in resolving the issue?